# CORS policy .net core e angular 8

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, iis, cors

Estou tendo problemas com CORS policy. Pulbliquei um site no IIS e não coloquei host name (acessava pelo IP). Quando coloquei o host name ([www.nome-do-site.com](http://www.nome-do-site.com)) o sistema parou de funcionar e o problema era:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://back' from origin 'http://front' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

No backend, o Startup.cs está codificado assim no método ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .Build())
        );
        services.AddMvcCore(options => { options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; }).AddJsonFormatters(); 
        services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = !_iHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });

        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });

        DomainServices(services);
        Repositories(services);
        Factory(services);
        ExternalService(services);
    }
```

E assim no método Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (_iHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        else
            app.UseHsts();

        app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
        );
    }
```

E mesmo assim está dando esse problema de CORS. Lembrando antes de mudar de "http://localhost/login" para "http://www.nome-do-site.com/login" não tinha esse problema.

Comment: Não coloque [saudações, cumprimentos, agradecimentos,...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) em perguntas ou respostas. Faça o nosso [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

Existe muitas coisas que podem ocasionar esse tipo de erro relacionado a Cors.
Coloca seu metodo Configure e ConfigureServices completo para poder analisar.
O que eu posso adiantar é que as configurações devem ter uma ordem conforme a [documentação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Em ConfigureServices, deve adicionar Cors antes dos Controllers.

```
 services.addCors();
 services.addControllers();
```

Em Configure, normalmente você define redirecionamentos, Rotas e depois Cors.

```
 app.UseHttpsRedirection(); //se existir, tente tirar pois o seu erro nao ta pedindo https
 app.UseRouting();
 app.UseCors();
```

EDIT:

Tente alterar o seu codigo assim:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()));


 
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");


    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
    );
```

Comment: Coloquei o código completo dos dois métodos, o que acha?

Comment: Desculpe a demora, mas o chamado ao app.UseCors deve vir depois de UseHttpsRedirection